# Decomposition of a self-adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a self-adjoint complex matrix $A$. We are given a particular orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$ such that $A$ can be written as $A = \sum_{i,j} \alpha_{ij}\, e_i e_i^*$ with all $\alpha_{ij} \geq 0$.

Does this necessarily mean that there exist vectors $\{x_j\}$ of the form $x_j = \sum_i \lambda_{j,i}\, e_{j,i}$ with coefficients $\lambda_{j,i} \geq 0$ in the same basis, such that

$$A = \sum_{i} \mu_i \,x_i x^*_i $$

with $\mu_i \geq 0$? The converse implication can easily be seen to be true, but I wasn't able to show this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Then $A$ is self-adjoint and each of its entries is greater than or equal to $0$. But one of its eigenvalues is smaller than $0$.

Comment: Thank you! Does the statement hold for positive semidefinite $A$, then?

Comment: @Luc Yes, it does.

Comment: Would you mind providing a quick proof? I still don't quite see it, even if I assume positive semidefiniteness.

Comment: @Luc It follows from the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) and the definition of semidefinite positive.

Comment: How does it follow that all of the coefficients of the vectors $\{x_j\}$ are non-negative? I'm sorry if I'm being stupid about this!

Comment: @LucI was talking about the $\mu_i$'s. Wasn't your question about them?

Comment: I need both the $\mu_i$ and the coefficients $\lambda_{j,i}$ for each vector to be non-negative.

Comment: @Luc If the matrix is positive semidefinite, then the $\mu_i$'s will be $\geqslant0$, but not, in general, the $\lambda_{j,i}$'s.

Answer (score 0):

The matrices for which such a decomposition exists are called completely positive. If the size if the matrix is larger than $4 \times 4$ then the things get more interesting. You can find relevant papers online.